# require() node module from Electron renderer process served over HTTP

Tags: node.js, require, electron, node-modules

Typically, in an Electron app, you can `require` node modules from both the main process and the renderer process:

```
var myModule = require('my-module');
```

However, this doesn't seem to work if the page was loaded via HTTP instead of from the local filesystem.  In other words, if I open a window like this:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
```

I can `require` a node module without problems.  But if I instead open a window like this:

```
win.loadURL(`http://localhost:1234/index.html`);
```

I no longer can `require` node modules inside my web page - I get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'my-module'` in the web page's console.  Is there any way to use node modules in an Electron page that was served over HTTP?

---

A little context: My company is building an application that needs the ability to be hosted as a web application *and* inside an Electron shell.  To make this simpler and consistent across both environments, my Electron app starts a local web server and opens the app hosted at `http://localhost:1234`.  Now I'd like the ability to add spell checking/spelling suggestions into the application using [`electron-spell-check-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-spell-check-provider).  This module needs to be imported and initialized inside the renderer process, so I'm trying to `require('electron-spell-check-provider')` inside my web page, but this fails with the `Cannot find module` error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems that the http version is getting some different actual paths for the files.  Try changing the require statement by:=> "require('./electron-spell-check-provider')"

Comment: Have you tried: `require('electron').remote.require('electron-spell-check-provider')` ?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? remote.require() works for me, but that's not always a good solution. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured this out. In the main process, figure out the absolute path to the node_modules directory, as in:

```
var nodeModDir = require.resolve('some-valid-module');
var dirnm      = 'node_modules';
var pos = nodeModDir.lastIndexOf(dirnm);
if(pos != -1)
    nodeModDir = nodeModDir.substr(0, pos+dirnm.length+1);
```

Now get this path to the renderer process via some IPC. Finally, in the renderer you can now require using an absolute path:

```
var mymod = require(nodeModDir+'some-valid-module');
```

Works perfectly for me with electron 1.6.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a preload-script which adds a property to the global/window variable. I named mine `appRoot`. `appRoot` just has the `__dirname` value of the preload-script. You then have to go from the folder of the preload-script to your module. I simply use `path.join()` to make it clean.
This is similar to @logidelic's approach, but without having to mess with IPC messages.

#### main.js

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: 'preload.js'
  }
})
```

#### preload.js:

```
global.appRoot = window.appRoot = __dirname
```

#### index.html:

```
<script>
  const { join } = require('path')
  require(join(appRoot, 'rendererApp'))
</script>
```

Comment: this did not work for me. this did:

```
const path = require('path')
const electron = require('electron')
const appPath = electron.remote.app.appPath
const usb = require(path.join(appPath, 'node_modules', 'usb'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Was having a similar issue. Try serving **renderer.js** over HTTP in your **index.html** like so,

```
  <script src="/renderer.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then, as per the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md), load your module in using the adding remote after the require in your **renderer.js** file.

`var spellCheck = require('electron-spell-check-provider').remote;`

Comment: What will renderer contain?