# Access node-based modules in renderer process securely

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

After reading [Electron's security tutorial](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security), I disabled `nodeIntegeration` and enabled `contextIsolation` when creating my instance of `BrowserWindow`. This has the effect that the renderer cannot load modules that depend on NodeJS APIs (such as `require()`). So, for example, I am unable to use `electron-store` (or `electron` for that matter).

This also means that I am unable to use IPC, even though I wouldn't be able to use IPC anyway because it JSON serializes my custom objects, which essentially causes object slicing by converting my custom object into a POJO.

With that said, what is the correct way to securely communicate between the main process and the renderer process. I want to create a Singleton app instance in my main process, access it in the renderer process (e.g., load configuration from disk, and then allow the user to view/edit it from the renderer, save the changes back to disk) as securely as possible.

I have looked at some other similar topics (e.g., [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370530/require-node-module-from-electron-renderer-process-served-over-http)) and it still doesn't work; besides, even if it worked, it's a hack and I'd like to avoid hacks if there are better ways that I'm just not finding on my own.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your content comes from. The security tutorial rightly points out that one should take extra care when loading remote content:

> Any resources not included with your application should be loaded using a secure protocol like HTTPS <sup>[1](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#1-only-load-secure-content)</sup>

If the content of your renderer process is packaged with your application, I think you can be a bit more relaxed about it:

```
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
}
```

In my case (YMMV) the `index.html` file isn't loaded from HTTPS but from the file system. That file is part of my codebase and shipped with the app itself and I can trust everything in it.